# How to get linux interface alias(IFLA_IFALIAS) programatically for an interface?

Tags: c, linux, networking

We can set alias to an interface using the command

```
ip link set eth0 alias somename
```

To see that;

```
ip link show eth0
```

It is set as an alias. Now I want to read this in a C program, and I am not having an idea. I did make a google search, and even tried to look into the iproute2 (provider of this cli), but to no avail. Can any of you help me on this?

Please refrain from giving cli output to file and regex solution.

Comment: My mistake, setting the alias command is mis-typed

"ip link set eth0 alias somename"

Comment: "alias command is mis-typed " then you may want to edit your question.

Comment: Thanks jbm, I had fixed it, in the question, as I commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do that in C, you'll have to do some [netlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) programming:

https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/

See [here about interfaces](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/route.html#link_object), and its section "3.5.11. IfAlias".

Netlink sockets are a very generic, extensible and thus powerful mechanism, yet this comes with a price of complexity and steep learning curve. Documentation is quite, er, "raw", and nothing close to a step-by-step extensive tutorial. You still can find some short tutos here and there, though for limited, simple use cases. Hence, expect quite a bit of work.

Another option would be to study the source code of `iproute2`, which *do use* netlink sockets, yet *not* relying on libnl* libraries but rather doing so all by itself, which 0/ (among other things) make it quite complicated 1/ does not help to create a re-usable outside of iproute2 implementation. I would *not* recommend this approach: as difficult if not more than using libnl*, plus libnl* knowledge is a reusable investment.

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/

PS:

There is a ("netlink")tag on SO[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netlink].

Comment: Thank you so much, I shall work with the netlink. This looks to be the solution I am looking for. Let me verify it.

Comment: You're welcome. Now be ready for a couple of tough days hacking with netlink (depending on your C experience).